# Sphinx + Oracle : Data source name not found error

Tags: oracle, sphinx, unixodbc

I want to connect to remote oracle database server and index some data from there with sphinx search engine. My OS is ubuntu 16.04 and I havc installed sphinx on it and tested it with local mysql database and **everthing was ok** (All the data indexed and I could search and results was correct) . I also have installed unixODBC and tested it with isql tool to remote access to oracle database server and **every thing was ok**, but when I want to index data with **indexer** command of sphinx this error occure:

```
sql_connect: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
```

Here is source block of my sphinx.conf file:

```
source src2
{
  type  = odbc
  sql_host = hostName
  sql_user = user
  sql_pass = pass
  sql_db  = dbname
  sql_port = 1521
  odbc_dsn    = DSN = mydsn; Driver={Oracle};Dbq=hostname:1521/dbname;Uid=user;Pwd=pass
  sql_query     = \
  SELECT tableId, Name \
  FROM sampleTable

}
```

And odbc.ini file:

```
[mydsn]
Application Attributes = T
Attributes = W
BatchAutocommitMode = IfAllSuccessful
BindAsFLOAT = F
CloseCursor = F
DisableDPM = F
DisableMTS = T
Driver = Oracle
DSN = mydsn
EXECSchemaOpt =
EXECSyntax = T
Failover = T
FailoverDelay = 10
FailoverRetryCount = 10
FetchBufferSize = 64000
ForceWCHAR = F
Lobs = T
Longs = T
MaxLargeData = 0
MetadataIdDefault = F
QueryTimeout = T
ResultSets = T
ServerName = MYDATABASE
SQLGetData extensions = F
Translation DLL =
Translation Option = 0
DisableRULEHint = T
UserID = user
Password = pass
StatementCache=F
CacheBufferSize=20
UseOCIDescribeAny=F
SQLTranslateErrors=F
MaxTokenSize=8192
AggregateSQLType=FLOAT
```

and odbcinst.ini file :

```
[Oracle]
Description= ODBC for Oracle
Driver  = /opt/oracle/instantclient_12_2/libsqora.so.12.1
Setup  =
FileUsage = 1
CPTimeout =
CPReuse = /usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
odbc_dsn    = DSN=mydsn;
```

i.e. w/o spaces around = after the DSN and since you have everything else specified in the ini file just the DNS should be enough. You also need only sql_query out of the rest sql_*. Like this:

```
source src2
{
  type = odbc
  odbc_dsn    = DSN=mydsn;
  sql_query     = \
  SELECT tableId, Name \
  FROM sampleTable
}
```

Comment: Nothing changed but when I addressed driver property directly like this Driver={/path/to/the/driver/libsqora.so.12.1}, this error occured: The error changed to : [unixODBC][Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied... .Considering these cases, I think sphinx can not access ini files, Correct me if not true and if it's true, how can I fix that?

Comment: @DAVID_ROA Try "Driver={/path/to/the/driver/libsqora.so.12.1};Dbq=hostname:1521/dbname;Uid=user;Pwd=password" then. The both work for me (either just DSN=mydns or as specified above)

Comment: I did it and it works now, but Why do I have to do this again (setting user and pass and driver address) when I make the settings in the ini files?

Comment: @DAVID_ROA What error do you get when you specify the DSN only w/o spaces around the =?

Comment: The same error that I said the first time: sql_connect: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified

Comment: @DAVID_ROA is your odbc.ini located at /etc/odbc.ini ? I can reproduce the issue if I move odbc.ini away from /etc/

Comment: odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini is located at /usr/local/etc/. Do you mean should I change tha path to /etc/ ?

Comment: @DAVID_ROA yes, try. It depends on how unixODBC is built for your system, in my case (centos 7) odbc.ini is expected to be either in /etc/ or in ~/.odbc.ini, the doc http://www.unixodbc.org/internals.html says more details (read from "odbc.ini"), but looks like /etc/ and the home dir are the defaults.

Comment: you're right. I just put odbc_dsn = DSN=mydsn; in the sphinx.conf file and changed the path of odbc.ini to /etc/ and it's working now.